# React + Fetch+ Json. TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: json, reactjs, promise, fetch, typeerror

When I used SuperAgent I didn't have this problem, but I decided to use  [Window.fetch polifyl](https://github.com/github/fetch) and I met this problem. I see all data was loaded, but it still shows error. 
Could your help me identify this error please:
[image: Screen Shot]

In render() I genereate a list of components based on an obtained list:

```
    render() {

    if (this.state.data.list) {
        console.log("render: " + this.state.data.list);
        var counter = 0;
        const list = this.state.data.list.map((item) => {
....
```

Comment: you are not closing 1st thenable call.

Comment: I imagine it like that:
after obtaining response, sent this response to a next function and the result of that function I send to a next function, but I didn't return any result. It means I don't transfer any data without return value from functions in the chain of functions....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The promise handlers in your screenshot won't work:

```
.then((json) => console.log('parsed json: ', json))
.then((json) => { this.setState({ data: json }); })
```

"Take the value from resolving this promise and pass it to `console.log`.  Then, take console.log's return value (which is `undefined`) and pass it to `this.setState`."

Comment: Thank you for hint! 
`fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            },
        }).then((response) => response.json()
            .catch(err => {
                console.err(`'${err}' happened!`);
                return {};
            }))
            .then((json) => {
                console.log('parsed json: ', json);
                this.setState({ data: json })
            })
            .catch((err) => { console.log('fetch request failed: ', err) }
            )`

Answer (score 3):

```
    fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
    }).then((response) => response.json()
        .catch(err => {
            console.err(`'${err}' happened!`);
            return {};
        }))
        .then((json) => {
            console.log('parsed json: ', json);
            this.setState({ data: json })
        })
        .catch((err) => { console.log('fetch request failed: ', err) }
        )
```